# How to debounce a normally closed switch?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, debounce

The 74LS192 IC's up count (pin 5) needs a logic 0 in order to count up. I'm trying to debounce the switch so that it doesn't give multiple inputs to the IC.

I've tried this circuit that is used for normally open switches, but my circuit uses a normally closed one.

[image]

Comment: Try redicomt R9 to about 100 Ohms. You need to sink about 0.4mA to drive it low.

Comment: The RC circuit helps both in switch open and close transitions. The difference being different time constants while charging and discharging the cap ( Switch open and close respectively). The cap discharges through the 1K resistor ( 1 time constant  = 1k*1u) and charges through 11k resistor ( 1 tc = 11k*1u). The rise time of signal at IC7 will be slow. You might have to check if there are any rise time requirements on input of IC7.

Comment: Why does it needs any different debouncing than normally open switch? Because in either case the switch closes or opens. The problem is more that it's a LS TTL chip, not the normally closed switch.

Answer (score 3):

As in the comments the simple cap on the input pin and two resistors may work fairly well to give some bounce reduction. Also in the comments is the fact that the arrangement will not be symmetrical for the rising and falling switching edges. That is not necessarily a problem, but there is a simple way to get both edges about equal (if that were desired). Just add a diode in parallel with R9 (anode towards the switch), then make R9 the same value as R8.  With that arrangement the charging of the cap is mainly through R8 (the diode by-passes R9). The discharge of the cap is then through R9. Because some logic families differ on their switching points you could adjust R8 and R9 for best operation. With that said there is still the issue of slow rising and falling edges that might cause problems. That condition could be improved by using a [logic gate with hysteresis](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Switch_Debouncing). Yet another option would be to use an [SR latch](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-debounce-in-digital-circuits/), (but then those options do start to become more complicated).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkMyzi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Debouncing with an SR latch can only be done with changeover switches, not the SPST switch the OP has.

Comment: Just a note that while a good explanation in general, the 10k in series won't work because the logic gate input is LS TTL type.